# Export all the netbeans project and database

Tags: java, mysql, database, servlets, export

I have a program develop for web application(java). I need to send my project to a friend. How can I export all my project and my mysql database to send to him.

Regards

Comment: You can use a version control system (such as Git or Mercurial for example, which are available in Netbeans) - save your projet (including the database) to a free online version control repository (for example bitbucket, there are plenty), give access to your repository to your friend who can then download the whole project in one click, and upload changes in one click, that you can in turn download in one click...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a good plugin for that on Netbeans : Export As Archive.

You can find more information about it there : [Export As Archive Plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/10235/export-as-archive)

You can also use [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) to dump your databases.

Another good way to do this is to use a Repository (with your project inside) with Mercurial (included in NetBeans too) - BitBucket.

You give an access to your friend and you can Commit whenever you make any change. It will protect you and your friend of making mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

1. Take all your java project and source files and zip them all into a file.
2. Use [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) to dump all your database into a file.
3. Zip everything and send the files to your friends :)

Comment: 1.a Remove the directory `.nbproject/private`